# Generic type T as variable name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

Im working with EntityFramework and I need some method which will synchronize incoming lists of entities with Database (overwriting records description or mark them as obsolete):

```
    public void Synchronize<T>(List<T> entityList)
    {
        //do something
    }
```

First of all I need to get all data from corresponding table and get difference between two lists (one unchangeable thing is entry's GUID).
For example if incoming entityList's type is User then I need to get all data from "User" table etc.

It doesn't work:

```
        var query = from entity in typeof(T)
                    select entity;
```

Of course I can do it old way:

```
switch (typeof(T).Name)
        { 
            case "User":
                var query = from user in User
                            select user;
                //Sync with User table
                break;
            case "Project":
                var query = from project in Project 
                            select project ;
                //Sync with Project table
                break;
        }
```

But maybe there is an elegant way to handle generic? Because I have a plenty of tables to synchronize. Thanks!

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems like you're trying to force the use of generics - when in fact the functionality of what you're writing depends entirely on type anyway (i.e. not very generic). Are you sure generics are fitting here?

Comment: You don't(shouldn't) need generics at all when code inside your method isn't generic.

Comment: my code may be used with generic as I think, because all my entities which will be synchronized comes out from ActiveDirectory and all of them include Guid, Description, Name and Obsolete properties. Thats why I may try to use generics here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to the [DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.103)) you could use the method `Set<T>` to do it.

```
var query = from entity in context.Set<T>() select entity;
```

But to make it work in your context you have to put at least a constraint on type T and the entities need to share a type or interface. Otherwise you cannot build your queries, cause T could be anything (`object`).

Comment: I guess `from x in y select x` could be shortened to just `y`.

Comment: @Heinzi, sure. I only want to display the use of this method in the context of the questioner

Comment: Thats what I need actually. And of course in actual code it wont be so simple as "from x in y select x"

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing generics for something that isn't generic. Maybe some part of your code is generic, but you should split that code off in another method.

You can use an interface to abstract away some functionality, but basically the answer is: you shouldn't do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

If it's OK for you to use ObjectContext, you can do it like this:

```
var octx = (ctx as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
var query = octx.CreateQuery<T>("SELECT VALUE v FROM " + typeof(T).Name + " AS v");
var result = query.ToList();
```

See more on CreateQuery here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339670(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Never use `(ctx as IObjectContextAdapter)` without checking `null` values!

Comment: That's totally nonsense. DbContext implements IObjectContextAdapter, so there is no way that it won't work.

Comment: Why aren't you casting it then?

Comment: And why, may I ask? What is the difference?

Comment: Well I'm asking you. From my opinion, simply semantics (which I value). As Eric Lippert states `"A cast communicates to the reader "I am certain that this conversion is legal and I am willing to take a runtime exception if I'm wrong". The "as" operator communicates "I don't know if this conversion is legal or not; we're going to give it a try and see how it goes".` http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx I suppose the use of either is subjective, I'm just asking the question.